# CAS overlay with CAS Management overlay error

Tags: java, tomcat, cas

I have installed tomcat-9.0.41
I build cas-overlay-template 6.3 and placed the cas.war in the webapps
started the server, everything works as it should.

I then build the cas-management-overlay 6.3 placed the cas-management.war in webapps but when I restart tomcat I get the following error when tomcat tries to load

firstly I dont understand what the exact problem is and how am I supposed to correct this "classpath" that the action is talking about.

any help would be appreciated!

```
2021-01-22 20:39:04,641 WARN [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext] - <Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'formContentFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MutableCoercionConfig com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.coercionConfigDefaults()'>
2021-01-22 20:39:04,666 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter] - <

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:175)

The following method did not exist:

    'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MutableCoercionConfig com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.coercionConfigDefaults()'

The method's class, com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/opt/cas/tomcat-9.0.41/webapps/cas-management/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.12.0.jar!/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper: file:/opt/cas/tomcat-9.0.41/webapps/cas-management/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.12.0.jar
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper: file:/opt/cas/tomcat-9.0.41/webapps/cas-management/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec: file:/opt/cas/tomcat-9.0.41/webapps/cas-management/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.11.3.jar
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeCodec: file:/opt/cas/tomcat-9.0.41/webapps/cas-management/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.11.3.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper
```

Comment: What do you use to compile `cas-management`? Your `jackson-databind`, `jackson-core` and `jackson-dataformat-xml` have incompatible version (cf. [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml/2.12.1)).

Comment: i just followed the instructions in the git as how to build, so i run

`./gradlew clean copyCasConfiguration build`

nothing special

Comment: I reinstalled everything into two different tomcat servers with different domains an i took the jar files from the cas installation in `/opt/cas/apache-tomcat-9.0.41/cas/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-*` and coppied them into `/opt/casmgmt/apache-tomcat-9.0.41/casmgmt/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/` and the casmgmt server server app started successfully. apparently the people who wrote the source of the overlays have some sort of misconfigurations as to what the depencies are and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the latest versions, reinstalled everything into two different tomcat servers with different domains. Which was not needed after all

I used as suggested

```
./gradlew clean copyCasConfiguration build
```

The error persisted.
So I took the jar files from the cas installation in

```
/opt/cas/apache-tomcat-9.0.41/cas/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-*
```

and coppied them into

```
/opt/casmgmt/apache-tomcat-9.0.41/casmgmt/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/
```

and the casmgmt server server app started successfully. apparently the people who wrote the source of the overlays either they don't have enough documentation as to what libs and versions should be used and when, or they have some sort of misconfigurations as to what the dependencies are and all

Comment: Gradle manages the dependencies of the project. Maybe it copied the wrong version or the is the bug in the gradle script. You experienced a minor mismatch between libraries (`2.11.3` vs `2.12.0`), which don't differ in almost anything.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i was actually expecting it to blow up when I copied the libraries over, and I was really surprise to see it work after all. I am a C and Perl developer so its kind of weird for me to have to deal with languages like Java